# Rails 5 can't find JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower

I installed a plugin (http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/) using Bower.

Now I have a file:

`vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery-bar-rating/jquery.barrating.js`

Also in my application.rb I have:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

I restarted my Rails server but when I access the app it says:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.barrating' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/xxx/Backend/app/assets/documentation
  /Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/xxx/Backend/app/assets/images
  /Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/xxx/Backend/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/xxx/Backend/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/xxx/Backend/vendor/assets/bower_components
```

So it looks in the right folder but still can't find the file.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure Bower install js into vendor folder, app root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't entirely remember how I did it a while ago, but I think basically if you need the file in the plugin within your js, you could do:

```
//= require jquery-bar-rating 
//OR
//= require jquery-bar-rating/jquery.barrating
```